# Inline Ckeditor: All buttons are disabled

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am currently trying to add an inline ckeditor to some text.

No javascript errors occour but unfortunately all tools are disabled and I can't edit the text.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/5LuyD/

Any one have a clue as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're missing is `contenteditable="true"` attribute for your element. If you want to have the editor customized (i.e. ran via `CKEDITOR.inline( element, cfg )`), set `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;` first.

With `CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;`, all the `contenteditable="true"` elements must be initialized manually to become an editor instance. See the [official guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) for inline instances.

Comment: Hey... Okay you are both right. I have to use contenteditable="true" - but also disableAutoInline = "true" as oleq told.
The solution: http://jsfiddle.net/5LuyD/2/

Thanks a lot to you both

Answer (score 2):

You missed the contenteditable="true" attribute for the tags that are editable!

Here is the fiddle. http://fiddle.jshell.net/5LuyD/1/

Comment: No!. If I use contenteditable="true" you will get the standart, unconfigured. When using the inlne() command, you can set what buttons you allow.

Comment: But for you to start! you need to set the contenteditable="true". If you don't do that, the text won't be editable and the buttons won't become active., give me a minute and i will check why your buttons sets won't work.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue despite setting `contenteditable="true"`, there is an issue with Chrome where contenteditable is set to false if the element (or parent element) is not visible.

See: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Solved-Chrome-Toolbar-buttons-grayed-out-for-INLINE-editor

The solution is to either a) ensure the element is visible before calling `CKEDITOR.inline()` or b) use a textarea instead of a contenteditable element (CKE adds a contenteditable div after the textarea in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue and I discovered a different fix for it. If the parent element (or the element itself) is originally set to display:none the contenteditable will = false (on chrome).

This fix worked for me:

```
var ck = CKEDITOR.inline(element);
ck.on('instanceReady', function(event) {
     var editor = event.editor;
     editor.setReadOnly(false);
});
```

Ref: https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9814

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the other suggested solutions worked.

The problem was that the id attribute of the div started with a numeric character (it was a GUID). Changing the id to begin with an alpha character worked: all the editor buttons were enabled.

For some reason, ckEditor doesn't like id's that begin with numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
                var ck=CKEDITOR.instances[i]; 
                ck.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {
                 var editor = ev.editor;
             editor.setReadOnly( false );
    });
}});
```